# R: How to filter rows where the start of entries match a list

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I have a very large dataframe (a snippet of it below) that I would like to filter. I would only like to keep the rows if at least one entry in the columns that start with "i10_pr" start with any values I have in `list`.

Here is an example of my dataframe and the list

```
#>     ID      visitorder i10_pr1 i10_pr2 i10_pr3 i10_pr4 i10_pr5 sum
#> 1   7466851          3 BW28ZZZ BR30Y0Z BR39Y0Z                   0
#> 2   7023336          1 0BDC8ZX 0BDC8W7 07D78ZX                   0
#> 3   2481935          3 5A09357 3C1ZX8Z 06HN33Z B54CZZA 0W993ZX   1
#> 4   4605446          1 5A1955Z 0BH17EZ 03HY32Z 02HV33Z GZ58ZZZ   3
#> 5   7287173          2 

list <- c("0B", "ND", "3J", "BW", "BR")                                           0
```

The output would look like:

```
#>     ID      visitorder i10_pr1 i10_pr2 i10_pr3 i10_pr4 i10_pr5 sum
#> 1   7466851          3 BW28ZZZ BR30Y0Z BR39Y0Z                   0
#> 2   7023336          1 0BDC8ZX 0BDC8W7 07D78ZX                   0
#> 4   4605446          1 5A1955Z 0BH17EZ 03HY32Z 02HV33Z GZ58ZZZ   3
```

Comment: Yes that is correct - thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create a regex pattern to `filter` the columns that `starts_with` `'i10_pr'` using `if_any` to find rows having at least one match

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
v1 <- c("0B", "ND", "3J", "BW", "BR")
pat <- sprintf('^(%s)', str_c(v1, collapse = "|"))
df1 %>%
    filter(if_any(starts_with("i10_pr"), ~ str_detect(.x, pat)))
```

-output

```
       ID visitorder i10_pr1 i10_pr2 i10_pr3 i10_pr4 i10_pr5 sum
1 7466851          3 BW28ZZZ BR30Y0Z BR39Y0Z    <NA>    <NA>   0
2 7023336          1 0BDC8ZX 0BDC8W7 07D78ZX    <NA>    <NA>   0
4 4605446          1 5A1955Z 0BH17EZ 03HY32Z 02HV33Z GZ58ZZZ   3
```

---

Or extract the first two characters and use `%in%`

```
df1 %>% 
    filter(if_any(starts_with("i10_pr"), ~ substr(.x, 1, 2) %in% v1))
```

-output

```
       ID visitorder i10_pr1 i10_pr2 i10_pr3 i10_pr4 i10_pr5 sum
1 7466851          3 BW28ZZZ BR30Y0Z BR39Y0Z    <NA>    <NA>   0
2 7023336          1 0BDC8ZX 0BDC8W7 07D78ZX    <NA>    <NA>   0
4 4605446          1 5A1955Z 0BH17EZ 03HY32Z 02HV33Z GZ58ZZZ   3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(7466851L, 7023336L, 2481935L, 4605446L), 
    visitorder = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), i10_pr1 = c("BW28ZZZ", "0BDC8ZX", 
    "5A09357", "5A1955Z"), i10_pr2 = c("BR30Y0Z", "0BDC8W7", 
    "3C1ZX8Z", "0BH17EZ"), i10_pr3 = c("BR39Y0Z", "07D78ZX", 
    "06HN33Z", "03HY32Z"), i10_pr4 = c(NA, NA, "B54CZZA", "02HV33Z"
    ), i10_pr5 = c(NA, NA, "0W993ZX", "GZ58ZZZ"), sum = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```